# How can I move photos from my iPhone to my computer?

Tags: macos, iphone

iTunes is generally the way you access files on your iPhone, right? Is there another way? I'd like to get the image files onto my OS X system so I can work with them as with any image file -- open them in Photoshop, attach them to emails, etc. The only option I can find in iTunes is to "sync" them "from" iPhoto. I don't want to mess around with iPhoto. I just want to get the files in a standard format like JPEG or TIFF and move them to a directory of my choosing. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Image Capture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_Capture), which comes with OS X should be able to do this. Upon plugging the device in it will allow you to download photos from it:

[image]

You may also like [PhotoToMac](http://www.galarina.eu/PhotoToMac/Home.html), it allows you to transfer them wirelessly.